# About some special kinds of group automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

let $G$ be a finite group with $1\neq Z(G) \lneqq G$. Also let $H=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ be the set of all disjoint representative elements of right cosets of $Z(G)$ in $G$.

Is there any non-trivial element in $Aut(G)$, call it $\phi$,  with the property that for each $x_i\in H$ we have $\phi(Z(G)x_i)=Z(G)x_i$ i.e. $\phi$ maps each element belongs to  $Z(G)x_i$ to an element in $Z(G)x_i$? What can we say if $G$ be a finite $p$-group?

Thanks in advance for any helpful guide.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360278 for previous discussion of this topic.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you so much for the reference, It was so useful.