# Understanding a terminology in a special type of group

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, terminology

I am trying to understand the following terminologies, and the resulting group (found in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360278/what-are-central-automorphisms-used-for)). In the original reference also, I didn't find the meaning of the terminology I am looking. It is this one: the following is quoted in the link given above-

> ...."We prove that every automorphism of a Chevalley group of type $B_l$, $l\geq 2$, over a commutative local ring with $1/2$ is standard, i.e., it is a composition of ring, inner, and central automorphisms."

I want to know the meaning of **commutative local ring with $1/2$ is standard**.  I know the meaning of commutative local ring.

I would be happy if one gives an explicit simple example of such ring with $1/2$ standard, and also, the resulting Chevalley group over it of type $B_l$, $l\geq 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is standard" modifies "automorphism." "With $\frac{1}{2}$" means that $2$ is invertible in the ring. That is, the sentence should be parsed

> We prove that every automorphism [of a Chevalley group of type $B_{\ell}, \ell \ge 2$, [over a commutative local ring with $\frac{1}{2}$]] is standard, i.e....

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I was mis-interpreting it and so confusing.