Meaning of the notation $Z_p(G)$
I am reading M. Hall Jr. and J. Senior's Groups of Order $2^n$, $n\leq 6$, and they use a notation I am not familiar with. They say on p. 5 that for certain $G$, (the abelian group) $Z(G) \otimes (G/G')$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$ consisting of those automorphisms which "induce the identity on $G/Z_p(G)$." Ordinarily, $Z_p(G)$ would be an element of the upper central series of $G$, but $p$ has not been defined, so I am not sure if this is a typo or what subgroup this is supposed to be. It seems like a neat proposition, though, so I'd be grateful for any help.
Edit: I'm also at a loss about how to get an automorphism of $G$ from an element of $Z(G) \otimes (G/G')$ in the first place. I assume it must be something noncanonical.

Can you specify the exact page in that book?

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, p. 5.

Maybe it is just a typo and $Z_1(G)=Z(G)$ is meant? What is $G$ in this context? I have read the section and don't understand anything, so cannot answer this.

$G$ is any group of minimal order in an equivalence class with respect to the relation of isoclinism.

Seems related to this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360278/what-are-central-automorphisms-used-for?rq=1 so perhaps the $p$ is just a typo.

The passage from the book deals with stem groups: in case of isoclinism (an equivalence relation on the class of groups, coarser than isomorphism; isoclinism works better for the classification of $p$-groups!) Philip Hall showed that in every isoclinism class there exist groups $S$ with the property that $Z(S) \subseteq S'$. These groups are called stemgroups. In the case of finite groups the stemgroups in a given isoclinism class are characterized by the fact that they are just the groups of smallest order in that  class. 
Concerning the passage in M.Hall and Senior, it is a typo, it should be $Z_1(G)$, so the center of $G$, and then it reads  (...) is isomorphic with the group of all automorphisms of $G$ which induces the identity on $G/Z_1(G)$, that is, Hall and Senior mean the group of central automorphisms, denoted by $Aut_c(G)$. In this particular case, since $G$ is a stem group, so $Z(G) \subseteq G'$, it follows that $G/G' \otimes Z_1(G) \cong Aut_c(G)$.
